# ssh slow before Authentications can continue

Tags: ssh

I've been googling on this problem for a while now, but I have not found a solution that works.
The problem is SSH login to my server is very slow all of a sudden. I can see it takes about 10 seconds before Authentications than can continue, here is my ssh verbose log:

```
OpenSSH_7.3p1, LibreSSL 2.4.1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 54.86.29.78 [54.86.29.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file .ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 54.86.29.78:22 as 'perfeyhe'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:g/REeuiZutP7YHv6WJR/vhm4kROJQ+9e0ODdd1Tuvpc
debug1: Host '54.86.29.78' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/admin/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
----------------------------------
takes about 10s
----------------------------------
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: .ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 54.86.29.78 ([54.86.29.78]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = zh_CN.UTF-8
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-74-generic x86_64)
```

and attachment is what I saw from wireshark:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeJm9.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The delay is on server so you can not see anything important in the client log nor in client side wireshark dump.

There are several possibilities which can cause this, but most probably there is `UseDNS` enabled in server `sshd_config`. Try to disable it (write `UseDNS no` to `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`), restart sshd service (`service sshd restart`) and try again.

If it will not help, set `DEBUG3` `LogLevel` in the same file, restart and see the server logs where it "hangs" and what does it wait for.

Comment: Also, I've faced long connection issue with `UsePAM yes` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue as follows:

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind
```

Found this in an answer by @HBruijn in this thread: https://serverfault.com/questions/707377/slow-ssh-login-activation-of-org-freedesktop-login1-timed-out.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I'm using UBUNTU 14.4 but there is no such a service named systemd-logind.

Comment: But It may be something wrong with my network, when I use ssh -vvv , I can see the time cost is between send packet: type 50 and receive packet: type 51. I tried  other terminal in different network environment , they won't cost such a long time.

Comment: what about sudo restart systemd-logind